# Get DOM element attribute, using php

Tags: php, dom, attr

If I have a PHP variable that is a string such as this:

```
$link = "<a href='test.jpg'>Download</a>";
```

How can I use the variable `$link` to get the value for `href` using PHP and not javascript?

Comment: since you're constructing the DOM using PHP in the first place you should know all the values that went into making it. 
You could split your string into the constant and attribute parts by making $link='test.jpg' and then outputting something like
echo '<a href="'.$link.'">Download</a>';

Comment: But I don't know all the values. The string for $link is generated dynamically and I want to extrapolate the value for href and use it elsewhere.

Comment: you could try extracting the value using a regex.. 

preg_match("/<a href='(.*)'>Download</a>/",$link,$matches);

...$matches[1] should then contain your link value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text big, you can use some library as [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), Zend DOM Query, Nokogiri or other. Otherwise, use **regexp**.